# Connection DB with entityFramework n-tier application

Tags: entity-framework, n-tier-architecture

i am building an restaurent reservation system , using asp.net mvc 4 entityframework, unity (for Ioc)  and unit of work , repository pattern. So i make 4 project to the solution on vs 2013 :

- RestaurentSyeteme (Web project ASP.NET MVC 4)
- RestaurentSystemeBusiness : i put business logic in this layer
- RestaurentSystemeDAL : Data access , entityFramework, repositories and context
- RestaurentSystemeDomain : my entities

here is the code for my dbContext :

```
public class RestaurentDbSystem : UnitOfWork
{

    public RestaurentDbSystem(string nameOrConnStr)
        : base(nameOrConnStr)
    {

    }
}
```

and here the UnitOfWork :

```
 public class UnitOfWork : DbContext, IUnitOfWork
  {
        public UnitOfWork(string nameOrConnString)
               : base(nameOrConnString)
        {

        }
  }
```

here is the code to configure my container (Unity) :

```
   private static IUnityContainer BuildUnityContainer()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();

        // register all your components with the container here
        // it is NOT necessary to register your controllers

        container.RegisterType<IUnitOfWork, RestaurentDbSystem>(new PerHttpRequestLifetime(),
            new InjectionConstructor("RestaurentDbSystem"));

        // e.g. container.RegisterType<ITestService, TestService>();            
        container.RegisterType<IClientService, ClientService>();
        container.RegisterType<IClientRepository, ClientRepository>();
        container.RegisterType<IRepository<User>, Repository<User>>();
        container.RegisterType<IRepository<UserType>, Repository<UserType>>();
        return container;
    }
```

and here what i put on my web.config to config connectionstring

```
<add name="RestaurentDbSystem" 
     connectionString="Data Source=LMA000049\mssqlserver;
     Initial Catalog=RestaurentSystemDb;Integrated Security=true"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I have created database with the name ='RestaurentSystemDb'.

The problme is when a execute the app i have this exception :

> An exception of type 'System.Data.ProviderIncompatibleException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: The text of your exception is missing.

Comment: The exception should tell you *much* more than this. It's impossible to analyze the error without these details.

Answer (score 0):

**RestaurentDbSystem** in `public class RestaurentDbSystem : UnitOfWork`

**RestaurentSystemDb** in `Initial Catalog=RestaurentSystemDb`

I think those two must be match.

Normally, if they are not same, Code-First tries to create a database on SQL Express.

Comment: i changed the name of the database, so Initial Catalogue was : RestaurentDbSystem, but i still have the probleme.